# Spring Boot JPA - return custom object with list

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a Spring Boot application with Spring JpaRepository.
I'm using my own query to return list of custom objects which are Groups with id, name and list of Teams.

So i have something like this:

```
public interface GroupDB {
    public Long getId();
    public String getName();
    public List<TeamDB> getTeams();
}
```

```
public interface TeamDB {
    public Long getId();
    public Long getWon();
    public Long getDrawn();
    public Long getLost();
    public Long getPoints();
}
```

My query returns this (I was trying to solve my problem on my own, this is why here is "team dot ..." but this is not working) :

```
SELECT
        id,
        name,
        team AS "team.id",
        SUM(win) AS "team.won",
        SUM(draw) AS "team.drawn",
        SUM(loss) AS "team.lost",
        3*SUM(win)+SUM(draw) AS "team.points"
...
```

and the query is very, very long, but if you want it, here it is: https://pastebin.pl/view/45b082f5

Then I make a request to database.

```
@Query(value = getGroupsFromGroupsStageQuery, nativeQuery = true)
List<GroupDB> getGroupsFromGroupsStage(@Param("tournament_id") Long tournamentId);
```

As an example: 
I wanted to get list with one group with id (8905), name ("Grupa 65") and list of four teams with: id, won, drawn, lost and points.
But the best thing I can get is list of 4 groups with ids, names and `null` assigned to teams

[image: example]

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will ever get a good solution using two entities as you have described. The team output is complex, so it is difficult to let JPA do a join to a group table with it.

I think you are better off pulling the complex team data, and separating it by group afterwards.

Here is a query that gives you a correct team data report.

```
drop table if exists match;
drop table if exists team;
drop table if exists team_group;
create table team_group (
  id serial primary key ,
  name text
);
create table team (
  id serial primary key ,
  name text,
  group_id int references team_group(id)
);
create table match (
  id serial primary key ,
  home_team int references team(id),
  away_team int references team(id),
  homeGoals int,
  awayGoals int
);

insert into team_group (name) values ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D');
select * from team_group;
insert into team(group_id, name) values
  (1, 'Manchester United'),
  (1, 'Arsenal'),
  (1, 'Chelsea'),
  (2, 'Real Madrid'),
  (2, 'Barcelona'),
  (2, 'Sporting Clube'),
  (3, 'Bayern Munich'),
  (3, 'Manchester City');
insert into match (home_team, away_team, homeGoals, awayGoals) values
 (1, 2, 3, 2),
 (1, 3, 0, 1),
 (2, 1, 2, 3),
 (2, 3, 2, 4),
 (3, 1, 1, 0),
 (3, 2, 4, 2),
 (4, 5, 1, 1),
 (5, 4, 1, 1),
 (5, 6, 2, 2),
 (6, 5, 2, 2),
 (6, 7, 3, 1),
 (7, 6, 1, 3);

with matchDetails as (
  select
    m.id,
    ht.id homeId, ht.name homeName, m.homeGoals,
    m.homeGoals - m.awayGoals homeResult,
    m.awayGoals - m.homeGoals awayResult,
    at.id awayId, at.name awayName, m.awayGoals
  from
    match m
      join team ht on ht.id = m.home_team
      join team at on at.id = m.away_team
  ),
winsCalc as (
  select
    t.group_id groupId,
    t.id teamId,
    t.name teamName,
    case when md.homeId = t.id then md.homeGoals else md.awayGoals end teamGoals,
    case when md.awayId = t.id then md.homeGoals else md.awayGoals end rivalGoals,
    case when md.homeId = t.id then md.homeResult else md.awayResult end result,
    case
      when md.homeId = t.id is not null then
        (case when md.homeResult > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
      when md.awayId = t.id is not null then
        (case when md.awayResult > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
    end win,
    case
      when md.homeId = t.id is not null then
        (case when md.homeResult < 0 then 1 else 0 end)
      when md.awayId = t.id is not null then
        (case when md.awayResult < 0 then 1 else 0 end)
    end loss,
    case
      when md.homeId = t.id is not null then
        (case when md.homeResult = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
      when md.awayId = t.id is not null then
        (case when md.awayResult = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
    end draw
  from
    team t
      join matchDetails md on
        md.homeId = t.id or md.awayId = t.id)
select
  distinct
  g.name groupName,
  wc.teamId,
  wc.teamName,
  count(teamName) over w gamesPlayed,
  sum(wc.win) over w wins,
  sum(wc.loss) over w losses,
  sum(wc.draw) over w draws,
  3*(sum(wc.win) over w)+(sum(wc.draw) over w) points,
  sum(teamGoals) over w teamGoals,
  sum(rivalGoals) over w rivalGoals
from
  winsCalc wc join team_group g on g.id = wc.groupId
window w as (partition by teamName)
order by
  teamName;
```